# Digit count program in python

Tags: python, while-loop

This is  a program which counts the no. of digits a user input in the programm.

```
n=int(input("Your no. :"))
dcount=0 
while n>0:
     dcount=dcount+1
print(dcount)
```

I make a while loop , was expecting the result but insted of counting the digits of the user input no. ,the output  is showing nothing.

Comment: You created an endless while loop for positive numbers. Try a negative number and it terminates. Btw you don't need a loop to count the digits.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count amount of digits in presented integer, you should divide `n` while `n > 0`, so your condition will work.

```py
n = int(input("Your no. :"))
amount = 0 
while n > 0:
    n //= 10
    amount += 1
print(amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

because the code was incomplete. print will only work when loop stop. in your code the loop will never stop, because the n value didn't come to zero. so you add n//= 10 inside loop. it will work. n//= 10 will reduce the digits one by one.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for contributing and adding an answer! The last part of your answer is a little less helpful. Here on Stackoverflow, we like answers to be as complete as the author can write them. Please explain for yourself what that n//=10 bit does.